# using LinkedIn API how to send HTML inside xml message

Tags: api, codeigniter, oauth, linkedin-api

hi i am using the linkedin api to send invitations . in the message

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<mailbox-item>
  <recipients>
    <recipient>
      <person path='/people/~'/>
    </recipient>
    <recipient>
      <person path="/people/abcdefg" />
    </recipient>
  </recipients>
  <subject>Congratulations on your new position.</subject>
  <body>You're certainly the best person for the job!</body>
</mailbox-item>
```

in the `<body>` section i am trying to add some HTML .

like

`<b>`You're certainly the best person for the job!`</b>`

but the problem is it is shown as text as it is in the message recieved by the friend , instad of that i want to `bold` the message content . how can i do this . is there any configuration should be done .

i am using codeigniter

```
function send_messeges($access_token, $xml_atring) {

    $profile_url = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox";
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
        <mailbox-item>
          <recipients>                
            ' . $xml_atring . '
          </recipients>
          <subject>'.$this->send_subject.'</subject>
          <body>'.$this->send_message.'</body>
        </mailbox-item>';
    $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $access_token, "POST", $profile_url);
    $request->sign_request($this->method, $this->consumer, $access_token);
    $auth_header = $request->to_header("https://api.linkedin.com");
    $response = $this->httpRequest($profile_url, $auth_header, "POST", $xml);        
    return $response;

}
```

please help .  thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to wrap html in xml, you have to use a construct like this:

```
<xmltag><![CDATA[<b>html text</b>]]></xmltag>
```

But be careful to read the api docs:

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/messaging-between-connections-api

> body  mailbox-item    yes The body of the message. Cannot contain HTML.
>   Must be editable by the member sending the message.

This shows you cannot use html here.

You can however use basic string formatting such as newlines to have at least some paragraphs:

This is done via `\n` (escaped newline) within the string.

Comment: so you are saying this is impossible !! , so i have no way to format my message , only i can do is send a raw text message...  :(

Comment: hmm .  so is there any pre defined xml tags equalant to html tags . like <br> == <linebreak> ???

Comment: No, the only thing you get to use in plain text is to try to use the normal escape sequence for linebreak: \n

Comment: Actually you should try these and see which works in this context: \\n  \n or \r\n

Comment: If the answer is correct - although it is not solving your problem, you might want to accept it.

Comment: @acctually this is not the correct answer for my question , this is a correct answer , but in my case this is wrong  :) . but your comment is correct .  \n solved the roblem for me , update your answer  , then i will accept it .